# `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string` in Angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`app.js` is:

```
directive('test', ['name', function ($name) {

                            return {/// DDO
                                template:'<h1>'.$name.'<h1>',
                                link: function () {
                                    console.log($name);
                                }
                            };
                        }]).
```

While above `name` a service, which I am injecting into above directive. Above code works fine and data shows up both in `console` and `web page`.

## BUT

error occurs when I replace `template: $name` with `template: '<h1>'.$name.'</h1>'`.
The error I get is this:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

So if I can't concatenate string named `$name` like that with `<h1>` tags then how do I do it there inside the `DDO`?

Note: Above given code is definitely not complete code, it's just the part I had problem with. Also service named `name` was declared/defined/created(or whatever it's called) by using [`value`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#value) function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenation in JS is done with the `+` symbol.

```
directive('test', ['name', function ($name) {
    return {/// DDO
        template:'<h1>' + $name + '<h1>',
        link: function () {
            console.log($name);
        }
    };
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

To concat string in `javascript` you have to use `+`

like this

```
'<h1>'+$name+'</h1>'
```

concat string by `.` is in `php` not in `javascript`